# The </ br> not working on a html5 app

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, smartphone

I have an application built in Html5 and wrapped in PhoneGap for Android

I have an auto-complete input

On drop-down list should appear in every instance linebreak, it works great on the computer, on Android not.

JS code:

```
        List = $.map(data.XXX, function (item) {
            return {
                label: item.X.split(":")[0] + "</br>" + item.X.split(":")[1],
                value: item.XX
            };
```

In smartPhone it shows me everything on one line

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: The correct one: `<br />`.

Comment: `</br>` is invalid HTML for a start.

Comment: Thank you all, it works now .. Do not have to vote down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `<br/>` .. I hope it'll work... :-)

Answer (score 1):

`</br>` isn't a proper tag, use `<br />`

Answer (score 1):

for html5 the correct version is `<br>`

`<br/>` is correct for xhtml 1.1